# AngularJS $http service not working on iPhone browsers

Tags: iphone, angularjs, http

$http service is not working on iPhone browsers, but its working fine on other devices browsers, after debugging what I have found is $http request is not reaching to server back-end.

**Here is my login function using in controller:**

```
function login() {
  $http.post(ENV.apiUrl+'/users/login', { email: $scope.username, password: $scope.password }).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}
 function handleSuccess(res) {
  console.log(res);
}
function handleError(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: please post along with your code

Comment: we will need some more information. what is the url you're calling ? what is the response code in your iPhone browser ?

Comment: @PatrickKelleter I don't know how to check response code in iPhone browser.

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: After debugging I got the issue and found the same problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409785/http-post-not-working-in-safari which helps me to fixed the issue.