# Protractor/PhantomJS gives DOM Exception 12 when trying to select a label

Tags: angular, phantomjs, protractor

I'm using Protractor with PhantomJS to test an Angular2 project. When run with Chrome, my tests pass fine, but with PhantomJS I get errors in tests that are trying to use a CSS selector to select a label like so:

```
element(by.css('label[for="my-id"'))
```

The error I get is:

```
Failed: {"errorMessage":"SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"74","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:15995","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_101)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"css selector\",\"value\":\"label[for=\\\"my-id\\\"\"}","url":"/elements","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"elements","directory":"/","path":"/elements","relative":"/elements","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/elements","queryKey":{},"chunks":["elements"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/3e10b5e0-d873-11e6-830b-4d293c6fcef6/elements"}}
```

Googling "DOM Exception 12", it [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315162/syntax-err-dom-exception-12-hmmm) related to how ID selectors are used, but I believe the way I'm using it is correct:

```
<label for="my-id">My Label</label>
<input id="my-id" type="text" ... />
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS selector is actually *invalid*, there is a missing closing square bracket:

```
element(by.css('label[for="my-id"]'));
                             HERE^
```

Note that you can catch this kind of problems early if you would use [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org/) with [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) in your IDE of choice. E.g. in WebStorm it would warn you on-the-fly:

[image]

Comment: Genius, absolutely correct and definitely something I had missed, thank you.